# Callback function vs return function in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback

I am new to node js. It seems callback function is the norm in writing functions in node. Is this true? What are the advantages of writing callback function compare to function returns the result? When should I write callback function and when should I just use the regular return function in node js?

Comment: Async programming is the reason you use callbacks. You should learn more about async programming using javascript.

Comment: You need to learn about asynchrony.  http://blog.slaks.net/2014-12-23/parallelism-async-threading-explained/

Answer (score 0):

The Node server is single threaded (for application code) and the reason you do callbacks in Node is to allow the thread to free up to do other processing while waiting for input/output. Normally this means that you simply use the asynchronous versions of all the calls (e.g. fs.readFile) and not the synchronous ones (e.g. fs.readFileSync).

You would write similar async calls if you are creating a module and you do async calls inside your module. Then your callers would need to provide you with a callback you can call to return the result.

You could also use a library like promise to return promises instead.

Answer (score -1):

Callbacks are low-level interface not meant for humans. You should wrap callbacks with generators, promises, async or whatever.

The ultimate advantage of this is that it's easy to perform stuff concurrently.

For instance, this syntax:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    arr.push(readSomeFile());
}
```

Will always mean that 1 file is read at a time, there is no way any compiler or transpiler can know that all the file reading can be done at the same time. So if reading 1 file takes 10ms, this code takes 100 ms to run, while it could potentially only take 10ms to run.

You simply cannot have the same syntax for those two different ways of doing it.

However you can get very close:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var fs = Promise.promisifyall(require("fs"));

Promise.coroutine(function* () {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        arr.push(fs.readFileAsync(...));
    }
    arr = yield Promise.all(arr);
})();
```

This also reads 10 files, but they will be read at concurrently instead of sequentially, something you can't do with synchronous syntax.

Comment: "Callbacks are low-level interface not meant for humans" with all the respect, that is not true. Callbacks may have problems, but they ARE meant for humans.

Comment: @vkurchatkin I don't mean callbacks in general but specifically in the case of connecting singular asynchronous actions together, you have to be ignorant to have that opinion - there are like 20 problems you need to keep in your head when using callbacks for this use case, that's far more than any other construct used in any other context. Asking yourself "what if this callback is called more than once here? what if this line throws synchronously?" and much more constantly as you are simply trying to do something that would be completely trivial otherwise is just ridiculous.

Comment: Of course the only way that is ok is if you are completely ignorant of such problems, hence you must be ignorant to find them usable. The buggy hello world example at nodejs.org frontpage is truly a testament to that ignorance.

Comment: Callbacks have issues, you have to think a lot, that is correct. But what you are saying is that no one is using them and everybody uses promises. That is not true.

Comment: @vkurchatkin oh that is not what I said at all, I said that you shouldn't use raw callback apis as is but should abstract  them with promises/generators/async (the library by caolan) etc